# Laravel: HTML in notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3

I'm using the default [notification system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications) (Laravel 5.3) to send an email. I want to add HTML tags in message. This does not work (it displays the strong tags in plain text):

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Info')
                ->line("Hello <strong>World</strong>")
                ->action('Voir le reporting', config('app.url'));
}
```

I know it's normal because text is displayed in `{{ $text }}` in the mail notification template. I tried to use the same system as in `csrf_field()` helper:

```
->line( new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString('Hello <strong>World</strong>') )
```

But it does not work: it displays strong as plain text.

**Can I send HTML tags without changing the view?** (I don't want to change the view: protecting text is OK for all other cases). Hope it's clear enough, sorry if not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can also create a new MailClass extending the `MailMessage` Class.

For example you can create this class in `app\Notifications`

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class MailExtended extends MailMessage
{
    /**
     * The notification's data.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $viewData;

    /**
     * Set the content of the notification.
     *
     * @param string $greeting
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function content($content)
    {
        $this->viewData['content'] = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the data array for the mail message.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function data()
    {
        return array_merge($this->toArray(), $this->viewData);
    }
}
```

And then use in your notification:

Instead:

```
return (new MailMessage())
```

Change it to:

```
return (new MailExtended())
```

And then you can use `content` var in your notification views. For example if you publish the notification views (`php artisan vendor:publish`), you can edit `email.blade.php` in `resources/views/vendor/notifications` and append this:

```
@if (isset($content))
<hr>
    {!! $content !!}
<hr>
@endif
```

We do it like this and works like a charm :D

Answer (score 30):

The `HtmlString` class works perfectly fine.
I've done this with *Laravel 7, 8 and 9*.

Try this and it should work

```
->line(new HtmlString("<b>This is bold HTML text</b>"))
```

Make sure to import this at the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;
```

Answer (score 16):

Run `php artisan vendor:publish` command which will copy `email.blade.php` to `resources/views/vendor/notifications` from `vendor` directory.

Open this view and change `{{ $line }}` to `{!! $line !!}` in two places. In Laravel 5.3 these are `101` and `137` lines in the view.

This will display [unescaped](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data) `line` strings which will allow you to use HTML tags in notification emails.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to add a bit of basic style to the template, you can use Markdown within the `line()` method without having to modify any other code.

Comment: so in this case  `->line("Hello **World**")`

Answer (score 3):

For anybody following @eric-lagarda's approach as I did, remember not to tab the content in the custom `email.blade.php` view as you would normally do in your views, as it will be interpreted by Laravel's markdown parser as code, wrapping the whole `content` HTML in `<code>` HTML tags. This caused me headaches but thanks to [this](https://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2017-54-markdown-email-doesnt-render-html) answer I managed to figure out what the issue was.
Your resulting bit of code to append to the `email.blade.php` view, will therefore be this (please note the missing spaces/tabulation before the curly brackets):

```
@if (isset($content))
<hr>
{!! $content !!}
<hr>
@endif
```